# Recursively obtaining kth smallest element in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion, partition

I'm trying to "translate" this algorithm from the pseudocode provided in my textbook. My program keeps crashing though, and I'm not really sure where I went wrong with my implementation. Here's the pseudocode in image with my code right below it: [image]

```
int kSmallFirst (int k, int anArray[], int first, int last) {
    int pivotIndex = 0;

    if (k < pivotIndex - first + 1)
        return kSmallFirst(k, anArray, first, pivotIndex - 1);
    else if (k == pivotIndex - first + 1)
        return pivotIndex;
    else
        return kSmallFirst(k - (pivotIndex - first + 1), anArray, pivotIndex + 1, last);
}

int main () {
    int i = 0;
    int arr[512];
    fstream data;
    data.open("data.txt");

    while (!data.eof()) {
        data >> arr[i];
        i++;
    }

    data.close();

    cout << kSmallFirst(42, arr, 0, i-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Here's an idea: separate the sorting and the input and test each independently. That may provide you with some useful information.

Comment: First of all, there is this new invention called debugger, you should probably give it a try before asking other people to debug your code for you. Second of all, if you do ask others to do that, the very least you can do is give some details about the crash, such as what the error message is, what line etc.

Comment: Even if I'm able to do modifications to your code, I can't really debug it, because your input comes from a file, and I'm having a hard time guessing what is in that file.

Comment: Print-out values of `k`, `first` and `last` for several recursive calls of `kSmallFirst` and post them here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is: you have **not implemented the main part of the algorithm**, which is described in your book with *italic* font:

> Choose a pivot value 'p' form 'anArray[first..last]'
>
> Partition the values of 'anArray[first..last]' about 'p'

These two lines are not a comment! They are the **pseudocode you're going to translate to C/C++** to make your code to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `kSmallFirst` never uses `anArray`, so contrary to what [JoriO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4050351/jorio) says this is not an input problem. Even if it did try to use a range `main` is passing the range [0 .. -1] in as `kSmallFirst`'s `first` and `last`.

You need to understand what the algorithm is doing, otherwise as is mentioned by [CiaPan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/733637/ciapan) you won't implement the most important part.

`kSmall` is:

1. Taking in a partition of `anArray` defined by `first` and `last`
2. Choosing a `pivotIndex` in the partition of `anArray` between `first` and `last`
3. Moving all elements smaller than `anArray[pivotIndex]` below `pivotIndex` and all elements larger than `anArray[pivotIndex]` above `pivotIndex`
4. This will define the next pair of partitions of `anArray`, the partition from `first` to `pivotIndex` and the partition from `pivotIndex` to `last`
5. `kSmall` will recurse on the range that will contain the `k`th element

Rewriting `kSmall` with this in mind will yield:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int kSmall(int k, int* anArray, int first, int last){
    int p = anArray[(last - first) / 2 + first]; // Choose a pivot value from anArray[first .. last]
    int* pivotIndex = std::partition(anArray + first, anArray + last, std::bind2nd(std::less<int>(), p)); // Partition the values of anArray around p

    if(k < pivotIndex - anArray){
        return kSmall(k, anArray, first, pivotIndex - anArray);
    }
    else if(k == pivotIndex - anArray){
        return pivotIndex - anArray;
    }
    else{
        return kSmall(k, anArray, pivotIndex - anArray, last);
    }
}
```

I'm sure you'll notice that the math in the if statement differs from the book. I've chosen to implement `kSmall`, as you did using `int` parameters, the book chose to use `int*` parameters.

Comment: Suppose the recursive call handles `anArray[2..4]`, then your proposed instruction `int p = anArray[(last - first) / 2];` will choose the item at index **-1**.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks, I forgot to add back in `first`

Comment: (upvote) Nice you simplified the `k` parameter handling, it is quite ugly in the base code to offset `k` with changing `first`.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks, I could have simplified further by doing `int pivotIndex = std::partition(...) - anArray;` but I thought it differed too much from the books implementation.

Comment: Well, following this way of thinkig, the ultimate simplification is calling `std::sort` and taking the resulting `anArray[k]`. However that might be somewhat against the teaching course of the OP's handbook... :)

Comment: @CiaPan LOL, in that vein it probably makes sense to suggest rather than trying to understand the book's procedure he simply re-implement QSort :)

Answer (score 0):

You choice of pivot index value is wrong.

Since this is a recursion you need to update your pivot for every call.

Make it more generic.

In the **kSmallFirst function**,

Use **pivotIndex = first**, rather than **pivotIndex = 0**.

Comment: That might possibly return the k-th item of the array, but not the _k-th smallest_ item.

Comment: Yes indeed,he never partitioned values around the pivot.                I was just pointing out the initialization part.